# How to get all text of div where user selected content?

Tags: javascript

```
window.getSelection().toString()
```

This line gets text selected by user. Is it possible to get also text that is next to it? Or get entire div which contains selected content?

I need some solution that don't require jQuery.

Comment: next to it? What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Have a try and open your browsers development console. In it's console tab execute the function call `window.getSelection()` whilst having selected some text on the loaded page. It returns an object (which is why you have to call `toString()` on it`). That object offers all you need, just take a look at it and explore yourself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at the output og getSelection() you see that you get the full data of the div container by using the following commmands:

```
var text = window.getSelection();
alert(text.anchorNode.data);
```